# Default state of apport messages in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apport

Well this is simple question seeking for simple answer:
**Are those annoying apport error messages turned off by default in Ubuntu 14.04 ?**

I know it is stupid to ask this question here, but google has nothing to say about it, and i don`t know who to ask.
And i really want to know it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not. 
I'm using Ubuntu desktop 14.04.2 and never had a error reporting pop-up messages up until i installed Oracle VirtualBox. While Oracle Virtual Box runs just fine, and does what it's designed to do, now after the install, upon rebooting the Ubuntu, I get pop-up crash/error messages generated by apport and it's annoying as hell.

There is a way to disable it, look at:

```
/etc/default/apport
```

There is a flag you can set to: `enabled=0`

and that will disable the whole error reporting shenanigans.

Do it at your own discretion, and if you need to turn it back on, just change the flag back to `=1` and reboot.